# List edge insets keeps changing - SwiftUI

Tags: ios, list, ipad, swiftui, sidebar

I have a SwiftUI app that uses a sidebar on iPad.

Using a `List` with the modifier`.listStyle(.sidebar)` the inset spacing no longer applies when rotating, however when I force close the app and reopen it appears normal.

**Cases where edge spacing no longer applies:**

- When user first signs in
- rotates device
- collapses sidebar and reopens)

[image]

The problem goes away when force quitting the app and reloading when user is signed in.

[image]

**ContentView**

```
struct ContentView: View {
   @State var signedIn = false

    var body: some View {
        if signedIn = false  {
            Text("Sign In").onTapGesture(){signedIn = true}
        } 
        if signedIn = true {
            AppSidebarNavigation()
        }
    }
}
```

**Sidebar**

```
struct AppSidebarNavigation: View {
    
    enum NavigationItem {
        case home
        case expenses
    }
        
    @State private var selection: NavigationItem? = .home

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            sidebar
                .navigationTitle("")
                .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
                .navigationBarHidden(true)
            
            // Main View
            HomeView()
            
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(DoubleColumnNavigationViewStyle())

    }
}

extension AppSidebarNavigation {
    
    var sidebar: some View {
            List(selection: $selection) {
                Group {
                    NavigationLink(destination: HomeView()
                        .environmentObject(store), tag: NavigationItem.home, selection: $selection) {
                            Label("Homes", systemImage: "house")
                            
                        }
                        .tag(NavigationItem.home)
                    
                    NavigationLink(destination: Expenses(),
                        tag: NavigationItem.expenses, selection: $selection) {
                            Label("Expenses", systemImage: "arrow.right.arrow.left")
                            
                        }
                        .tag(NavigationItem.expenses)
                        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.large)
                }

            }
            .listStyle(.sidebar)
    }
}
```

Comment: No one can compile the code you've supplied, so it's somewhat unlikely that you'll receive a useful answer here. Consider making a [mre].

Comment: Not reproducible with provided code, Xcode 13.4 / iPadOS 15.5. It might be in different code. Needed MRE.

Answer (score 3):

So I would consider trying

```
.listRowInsets(EdgeInsets(top: 8, leading: 8, bottom: 8, trailing: 8))
```

or

```
.listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
```

Even add

```
.listRowInsets(.init())
```

However your problem may be due to your subviews overriding TableView rows. Check if you have something like (I am not sure the exact code)

```
init() {

    UITableViewCell.removeEdgeInsets

}
```